# Assertion fails as it does not wait for promise resolution

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, promise, sinon, stub

I use mocha, sinon and chai to run a set of tests. Here is the method I'm testing

```
fn.method().then(function(response) {
  console.log(response)
  test()
})
```

I have stubbed out the `method` like this

```
test = sinon.spy()  
fn = { method: sinon.stub().resolves("hello") }
```

In my test I have

```
expect(fn.method()).to.have.been.called
console.log("goodbye")
expect(test).to.have.been.called
```

I expect the tests to pass and print "hello" and "goodbye" in sequence but what I see is `expect(test).to.have.been.called` fails and further more I see that the "hello" gets printed after "goodbye".

What would be the right way to test that `test` is called after the promise resolves?

Comment: You should look across async and await : [Link to reference][1]


  [1]: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's failing because (presumably) there is enough asynchronicity in the sinon `.resolves` hook that your two lines

```
console.log("goodbye");
expect(test).to.have.been.called;
```

run before the code within the `.then` block of your tested method runs.  (We know it's running because we see the console being logged, but we know that it must be running *after* the second `expect` line.)

I would unwrap your stubbed method from its expect, maybe something like:

```
// in test.js

fn.method().then(() => {
  expect(test).to.have.been.called;
});
```

Comment: Argh. I thought I tried this and it wasn't working (It threw a `then is undefined` error) but I was doing `fn.method.then()` instead of `fn.method().then()`. D'oh. Thanks!